# NumPy random shuffle rows independently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, shuffle

I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[  1,  2, 3],
              [  1,  2, 3],
              [  1,  2, 3]])
```

I understand that `np.random.shuffle(a.T)` will shuffle the array along the row, but what I need is for it to shuffe each row idependently. How can this be done in numpy? Speed is critical as there will be several million rows.

For this specific problem, each row will contain the same starting population.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5173

Comment: @jpp The original question didn't ask for per column, nor have the answers thus far tried to solve for it. So, rolling back to old title. It's an easy extension for the accepted solution, but might confuse people looking for that specific case.

Comment: @Divakar, the point is the *answer* is the same (simply changing `axis=-1` to `axis=0`). And the title change is trivial *in order for more people to find unutbu's excellent solution*. There was no hidden motive here, except to improve SO. Do you disagree?

Comment: @jpp And the advanced indexing part. We have improved it with the dup linking, but as I said for people looking for per column basis case, they might not know how to extend. So, they might follow the linked dup one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2018)

def scramble(a, axis=-1):
    """
    Return an array with the values of `a` independently shuffled along the
    given axis
    """ 
    b = a.swapaxes(axis, -1)
    n = a.shape[axis]
    idx = np.random.choice(n, n, replace=False)
    b = b[..., idx]
    return b.swapaxes(axis, -1)

a = a = np.arange(4*9).reshape(4, 9)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
#        [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
#        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
#        [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

print(scramble(a, axis=1))
```

yields

```
[[ 3  8  7  0  4  5  1  2  6]
 [12 17 16  9 13 14 10 11 15]
 [21 26 25 18 22 23 19 20 24]
 [30 35 34 27 31 32 28 29 33]]
```

while scrambling along the 0-axis:

```
print(scramble(a, axis=0))
```

yields

```
[[18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

---

This works by first swapping the target axis with the last axis:

```
b = a.swapaxes(axis, -1)
```

This is a common trick used to standardize code which deals with one axis.
It reduces the general case to the specific case of dealing with the last axis.
Since in NumPy version 1.10 or higher `swapaxes` returns a view, there is no copying involved and so calling `swapaxes` is very quick.

Now we can generate a new index order for the last axis:

```
n = a.shape[axis]
idx = np.random.choice(n, n, replace=False)
```

Now we can shuffle `b` (independently along the last axis):

```
b = b[..., idx]
```

and then reverse the `swapaxes` to return an `a`-shaped result:

```
return b.swapaxes(axis, -1)
```

Comment: this is very useful and it is the first time that I see this kind of indexing `a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], idx]` it seems very interesting way of working with arrays but it does not seem to be covered by the numpy tutorial. Could you provide references to tutorials or could you explain the rationale of what you are doing here? Thanks

Comment: @Gioelelm: `a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], idx]` is of the form `a[ind_1, ind_2]`, where `ind_1` and `ind_2` are integer-valued arrays. `a[ind_1, ind_2]` is an example of [integer array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). In particular, look at the second example shown on the linked page. 
Once you grok integer array indexing, the code above should be much clearer.

Comment: @Gioelelm: (cont'd) The only added little twist is that `np.arange(a.shape[0])` is a 1D array, and [`[:, None]` is being used](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to make `ind_1` a 2D array of shape `(a.shape[0], 1)`. When used together in a[ind_1, ind_2]`, the indexing arrays `ind_1` and `ind_2` [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the same shape -- `(a.shape[0], 1)` broadcasts to `a.shape`.

Comment: Thank you. I realised I never had a deep understanding of integer array indexing using >1d arrays. Everything is clear now. I have always been using `a[np.ix_(rows, cols)]` when I want to select all the rows and columns that match, instead of the diagonal elements but I never realised that what was happening under the hood is that `rows` and `cols` were broadcasted to have `a.shape`.

Comment: @UlfAslak: Thank you for alerting me about this bug. I believe it's now fixed.

Comment: Such speed! Very nice :)

Comment: Notice that the shuffle is the same for each row, indexed by `idx`. You are still not getting a different shuffling for each row.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Each row is shuffled in the same manner. I can achieve that with simple indexing.

Answer (score 4):

As of NumPy 1.20.0 released in January 2021 we have a [`permuted()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html) method on the new `Generator` type (introduced with the new random API in NumPy 1.17.0, released in July 2019). This does exactly what you need:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
])
shuffled = rng.permuted(a, axis=1)
```

This gives you something like

```py
>>> print(shuffled)
[[2 3 1]
 [1 3 2]
 [2 1 3]]
```

As you can see, the rows are permuted independently. This is in sharp contrast with both `rng.permutation()` and `rng.shuffle()`.

If you want an in-place update you can pass the original array as the `out` keyword argument. And you can use the `axis` keyword argument to choose the direction along which to shuffle your array.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a `return` value and want to operate on the array directly, you can specify the indices to shuffle.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>>
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
>>>
>>> # Shuffle row `2` independently
>>> np.random.shuffle(a[2])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1]])
>>>
>>> # Shuffle column `0` independently
>>> np.random.shuffle(a[:,0])
>>> a
array([[3, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

If you want a return value as well, you can use [`numpy.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html), in which case replace `np.random.shuffle(a[n])` with `a[n] = np.random.permutation(a[n])`.

Warning, do not do `a[n] = np.random.shuffle(a[n])`. `shuffle` does not `return` anything, so the row/column you end up "shuffling" will be filled with `nan` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer above. But I will throw in a quick and dirty way:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
ignore_list_outpput = [np.random.shuffle(x) for x in a]
Then, a can be something like this
array([[2, 1, 3],
       [4, 6, 5],
       [9, 7, 8]])
```

Not very elegant but you can get this job done with just one short line.

Comment: This will take a very long time to execute I believe as its not pure numpy

Comment: The idea is same as np.apply_along_axis which is pure numpy function. But this function also processes each row by row. You will not have a lot of performance gain.

Comment: Basically you are rearranging numpy array in memory row by row.

Comment: Can you time it and see how it performs with 2m lines?

Comment: I think that's your job :-)

Comment: What's the result?

Comment: It's the same. I tried ´[np.random.shuffle(x) for x in X]´ vs ´np.apply_along_axis(np.random.shuffle, 1, X)´ and when X is very large there is no difference in runtime (tested with jupyter magic ´%timeit´). For small matrices, np.apply_along_axis is, however, SLOWER! For this ´a´, its in fact on average four times faster to use ´[np.random.shuffle(x) for x in X]´.

Answer (score 1):

Building on my comment to @Hun's answer, here's **the fastest way** to do this:

```
def shuffle_along(X):
    """Minimal in place independent-row shuffler."""
    [np.random.shuffle(x) for x in X]
```

This works in-place and can only shuffle rows. If you need more options:

```
def shuffle_along(X, axis=0, inline=False):
    """More elaborate version of the above."""
    if not inline:
        X = X.copy()
    if axis == 0:
        [np.random.shuffle(x) for x in X]
    if axis == 1:
        [np.random.shuffle(x) for x in X.T]
    if not inline:
        return X
```

This, however, has the limitation of only working on 2d-arrays. For higher dimensional tensors, I would use:

```
def shuffle_along(X, axis=0, inline=True):
    """Shuffle along any axis of a tensor."""
    if not inline:
        X = X.copy()
    np.apply_along_axis(np.random.shuffle, axis, X)  # <-- I just changed this
    if not inline:
        return X
```

Comment: Great work! For a huge matrix, this in-place shuffling should be the way to go. For not in-place, you could use np.random.permutation or np.random.choice. In that way, not need to copy the array explicitly, probably a more readable/cleaner code, and a good way to emphasize the in-line nature of np.random.shuffle().

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with numpy without any loop or extra function, and much more faster. E. g., we have an array of size (2, 6) and we want a sub array (2,2) with independent random index for each column.

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([[1, 1],
                 [2, 2],
                 [0.5, 0.5],
                 [0.3, 0.3],
                 [4, 4],
                 [7, 7]])

id_rnd = np.random.randint(6, size=(2, 2))  # select random numbers, use choice and range if don want replacement.
new = np.take_along_axis(test, id_rnd, axis=0)

Out: 
array([[2. , 2. ],
       [0.5, 2. ]])
```

It works for any number of dimensions.