# Shuffle independently within column of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

I have a numpy array of the format

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Each column represents a data channel, and I need to shuffle the contents of each column within that column *independently* of the other channels. I understand that `numpy.random.shuffle` only shuffles along the first axis of the array ie. shuffles the order of rows within the array. What is the best way to carry out an independent shuffle within each column?

Comment: A simple for loop and treating each column as a normal list may be easiest https://stackoverflow.com/a/976918/7304372

Comment: Use @unutbu's [numpy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273313/9209546) with `axis=0`. Marked as duplicate.

Comment: `arr[:, n] = numpy.random.permutation(arr[:, n])` where `n` is the column index.

Comment: @droooze, this may work. But I suggest you post on the duplicate answer.

Comment: @jpp Mine looks closer to @ unutbu's one. So, I think we are covered there. Good find there.

Comment: @jpp done, I guess the question warrants another answer which is more direct.

Comment: @droooze, I upvoted it as a valid answer. This benefits everyone. In the long run, good answers are more likely to get views/upvotes on a canonical question/answer page than on dups like this.

Comment: I think I will undelete my solution here, as the linked dup target doesn't show how to translate for per column basis as asked here. Won't vote to re-open though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could generate unique row indices for each column and index into the the input array with `advanced-indexing`. To generate the unique indices, we would use [`random float generation + sort` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438143/3293881), thus giving us a vectorized solution, like so -

```
idx = np.random.rand(*a.shape).argsort(0)
out = a[idx, np.arange(a.shape[1])]
```

**Generic version**

We could generalize it to cover generic `n-dim` arrays and along generic `axes` with [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) and end up something as listed in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317373/).

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I needed to do. Would not have thought of this on my own.