# Columns of each row in 2D Numpy array do not shuffle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to shuffle each row's columns independently in a Numpy 2D array and I tried using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426584/shuffle-independently-within-column-of-numpy-array/49426735#49426735), but my array stays the same as before the operation. Here is my code:

```
perms = np.random.rand(*deltas.shape).argsort(1)    #deltas is a 2d array of float values
deltas = deltas[perms, np.arange(deltas.shape[1])]
```

As I said `deltas` stays the same as before after executing `deltas = deltas[perms, np.arange(deltas.shape[1])]`. I cannot find the problem. I have a Numpy version 1.16.2

EDIT:
It seems my indexing is not correct, since it shuffles correctly if I call `.argsort(0)`, but I want it to work with `.argsort(1)`.

Comment: You need to use `perms` as column indices, so `deltas[np.arange(deltas.shape[0])[:,None], perms]` I think.

Comment: Updated my answer there to shuffle along a generic axis.