# indexing a numpy array by an array of indices in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, variable-assignment

i have a vector i want to shuffle in batches.
the idea i came up with is to reshape it into 2D array with each row as a batch.
then i shuffle each row on its own.

this is toy example of the approach

```py
# shuffle the matrix
mat_size = (8, 8)
row_size = 4

# generate the row and column indices
# shuffle the column
col_idx = np.arange(mat_size[0] * mat_size[1], dtype = np.int32) 

tmp_mat = np.reshape(col_idx, (-1, row_size))

for row in tmp_mat:
  idx = np.random.choice(row_size, size = row_size, replace = False)
  row[idx] = row # in place on col_idx

tmp_mat
```

the result i get:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  4],
       [ 8,  9,  9,  8],
       [12, 12, 14, 12],
       [16, 17, 17, 19],
       [21, 20, 20, 21],
       [25, 26, 24, 24],
       [28, 29, 28, 31],
       [33, 34, 32, 32],
       [36, 36, 38, 38],
       [40, 41, 41, 43],
       [44, 44, 46, 46],
       [48, 48, 50, 48],
       [53, 52, 53, 52],
       [56, 57, 56, 57],
       [61, 60, 62, 60]])
```

the issue is that the rows are not a shuffled version of the input rows.
it can be seen as the original array has unique values per row.
i am not sure what happens here.

i did found out that if i replace `row[idx] = row` with `row[:] = row[idx]` it works.

is there an explanation to what is going on?
why is the assignment not working as i expect?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is due to trying to modify the row while referencing it. So, internally, when you access an item in the right-hand side, if might have been replaced already.

You don't have the issue if you use a copy:

```
row[idx] = row.copy()
```

Nor, as you found out by doing:

```
row[:] = row[idx]
```

which is also using a copy.

Note that you can shuffle your array in a vectorial way using [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273313/16343464):

```
def scramble(a, axis=-1):
    """
    Return an array with the values of `a` independently shuffled along the
    given axis
    """ 
    b = a.swapaxes(axis, -1)
    n = a.shape[axis]
    idx = np.random.choice(n, n, replace=False)
    b = b[..., idx]
    return b.swapaxes(axis, -1)

out = scramble(tmp_mat)
```

Or relatively efficiently, if you have a limited number of columns:

```
out = tmp_mat[np.arange(tmp_mat.shape[0])[:,None],
              np.argsort(np.random.random(tmp_mat.shape))]
```

Or [`numpy.random.Generator.permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html):

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
out = rng.permuted(tmp_mat, axis=-1)
```

##### timings

(on the provided example):

```
# loop
164 µs ± 5.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# scramble
13.5 µs ± 536 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# argsort
6.01 µs ± 511 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# permuted
2.21 µs ± 82.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

On 10k rows:

```
# loop
100 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# scramble
29.7 µs ± 673 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# argsort
777 µs ± 61.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# permuted
511 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: i see. i'd assume the internal code will handle this.

Comment: isn't the suggested code in `scramble` applies the same shuffle to each slice?

Comment: @EricJohnson no, the suggested alternatives are shuffling all rows independently

Comment: @mozway There is also [`Generator.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html) (or `permuted` if you want a new array)

Comment: @mozway, it does apply the same shuffling. try `my_array = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]); scramble(my_array)`. all rows will have the same shuffling.

Comment: Oops, only permuted works ;)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs that's right, thanks, I'll add it!